# Problems with RODBC sqlSave, Error in odbcUpdate

Tags: sql, r, cran, rodbc

I am trying to insert my data into my SQL using RODBC

This is the code I am using:

```
    sqlSave(
  odbcChannel,
  final,
  tablename = "SRP_KAZ_Mega_Shipment_Plan",
  rownames = FALSE,
  colnames = FALSE,
  safer = TRUE,
  fast = TRUE,
  append = TRUE,
  varTypes = c(
    филиал = "nvarchar(250)",
    SKU = "nvarchar(250)",
    Month = "datetime",
    Volume = "float",
    Feature = "nvarchar(250)",
    Period = "nvarchar(250)" 


  )
)
```

And this is what I get:

```
    Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  : 
  missing columns in 'data'
```

I don't know what is wrong here, but whenever I run the exact same code and data on other computers it works perfectly fine.
Any ideas of what this might be will do.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to `sqlSave()` and it worked for me:

```
,fast = F
```

I found the answer from ChristyCasey in the following post:
[Problems with RODBC sqlSave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910592/problems-with-rodbc-sqlsave)